# Github found dependency vulnerability in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, nokogiri

I have been receiving messages that GitHub found known dependency vulnerability in my Gemfile.lock, this is loofah (2.0.3) and Nokogiri (1.7.0.1) but these gems are dependencies I did not specifically asked for (other gems do depend on them) in my Gemfile, so, what can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Gemfile.lock`, you can see which one of your dependencies pulls in those libraries, and what their version constraint is.

```
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
  loofah (~> 2.0)
```

With Rails, `loofah` is required by `rails-html-sanitizer` and the version must just be greater than `2.0`. If a version is locked, the `Gemfile.lock` will read `= 2.0`.

Since it is not locked, you can use `bundle update loofah` to install a more recent version that does not suffer from the security vulnerability. Or `bundle update` if you want to update all gems...

Should a version to locked, you have to check if the gem that declares the dependency has a newer version that updates its locked dependency (e.g. a new version of `rails-html-sanitizier` that updates `loofah`). With security issues, these updates normally happen pretty quickly. You would then update `rails-html-sanitizier` to get a new version of `loofah`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your gemfile.lock and see which libraries are requiring these gems a dependencies.  Then you can proceed to update replace or remove those libraries until you no longer have vulnerabilities.